# trying to stream music using soundcloud sdk

Tags: api, sdk, streaming, soundcloud

hi guys am new to java script..

I am trying to stream a sound track in soundcloud using their java script SDK but my code is not working please let me know how to make this work. Below is my code

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html><head>
  <script src=”http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js”></script>

  <script src=”http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js”></script>

  <script>

  SC.initialize({

  client_id: “15c5a12b5d640af73b16bd240753ffbb?,

  redirect_uri: “http://connect.soundcloud.com/examples/callback.html”

  });
  $("#stream").live("click", function(){
      SC.stream("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/293", {autoPlay: true});
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="button" href="#" id="stream" class="big button" value="Stream It Again, Sam" />
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things I can spot, that may just be a result of copy & pasting your code, but good to check anyways:

1. You've got a combination of smart quotes (i.e. `”`) and dumb quotes (i.e. `"`) in your code. Change all of the smart quotes to dumb quotes.
2. Your `client_id` has a `?` appended to it. Replace the `?` with a `"`.

Make those changes, reload and you should be off to the races.

Btw, for your example here you can also omit the `redirect_url`. Having it there won't do any harm though:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: "15c5a12b5d640af73b16bd240753ffbb"
});
```

Comment: hi i made those changes still same problem... I need to only play the track and stop it when clicked on a stop button could you give one working example...

Comment: I am getting the error "Failed to load Resource file://connect.soundcloud.com/soundmanager2/soundmanager2.js " in console.. Please let me know how to resolve this..

Comment: You'll have to run it from a web server, not your filesystem. Easiest thing to do is use a public Dropbox folder or something.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul !! I put the html file in dropbox public folder and tried it was working fine. I copied the public link of that file          http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108992201/streaming.html and tried to open it via android webview in a mobile app the script is not working as expected... how to use the same javascript and jquery for mobile devices please advise

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the changes mentioned above, changing the JQuery version to 1.4 worked for me.